# Flip animation between two UIWebView

Tags: ios, animation, uiwebview, flip

I would like to flip animate between two UIWebViews inside one UIViewController.

I have put all together in the storyboard but I'm only able to flip between two UIViewControllers.

Any idea how to flip between two UIWebViews with the flip horizontal animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have view1 and view2, flipping from view1 to view2:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:view1 cache:YES];
[view1 addSubview:view2];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I didn't try my code but I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. will this switch between the UIWebView or between the UIViewController? also how can i excecude the code when the user touches the UIWebView?

Comment: UIWebView is a subclass of UIView, because so you can switch it too. You have to know where you can use this code, I can't know what you keep in mind